# How do I dynamically use Selenium's @FindBy?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber

I am going to run selenium with cucumber over [this page](http://suvian.in/selenium/1.6checkbox.html). Here is the cucumber scenario and outline

```
@tag
Feature: Check the checkbox
  Webdriver should be able to check the checkbox lists

  @tag1
  Scenario: Check the checkbox
    Given I am in checkbox task page 
    When I can check the hobbies from the checkbox
    And I click on "Next Task"
    Then It navigates to the next task

  @tag2
  Scenario Outline: Title of your scenario outline
    Given I am in "http://suvian.in/selenium/1.6checkbox.html"
    When I can check the <id> from the checkbox
    And I click on "Next Task"
    Then It navigates to the "http://suvian.in/selenium/1.7button.html"

    Examples: 
       | id |
       |  1 |
       |  2 |
       |  3 |
       |  4 |
```

Then in the POM (page object model), the id of the checkboxes as `checkId`. I have the following:

```
public class CheckBoxPage {

    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="????")
    public WebElement checkId;
}
```

I don't know how I should set the `using` part. The issue is that the `Id` varies from `1 to 4`.

Comment: It is not advisable to include technical details like ids in scenarios. You are better off using the value instead, makes it more clear. Use the driver.findElement and pass a dynamically generated xpath to it instead of findby annotation...

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. The `@FindBy` annotation expects `using` to be a String constant, which is impossible to dynamically set up.

Why not just define all four checkboxes in `CheckBoxPage`? It is not as if the amount of checkboxes on the page will ever change.

```
public class CheckBoxPage {

    @FindBy(how= How.ID, using="1")
    private WebElement singingCheckbox;

    @FindBy(how= How.ID, using="2")
    private WebElement dancingCheckbox;

    @FindBy(how= How.ID, using="3")
    private WebElement sportsCheckbox;

    @FindBy(how= How.ID, using="4")
    private WebElement gamingCheckbox;
}
```

Comment: so, what is solution in concept of POM?

Comment: @Salman Define all four checkboxes and only test the one used in the current scenario outline.

Comment: maybe it works, but there should be an easier solution

Comment: @Salman With CheckBoxPage you are modeling a static page, why do you so desperately want to define it dynamically? If someone updates your scenario using a non-existing id, it will also render a page with checkbox elements that can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can set dyanic value for identifier using PageFactory as it takes `constant String` as value

However if you really have to achieve this, you can create the element inside the step and click on it as mentioned below.

```
Feature: Check the checkbox
  Scenario Outline: Click all Check Boxes
  Given I am in "http://suvian.in/selenium/1.6checkbox.html"
  Then It should click <id> checkbox
    Examples:
    | id |
    |  1 |
    |  2 |
    |  3 |
    |  4 |
```

**Step Definition**

```
   @Given("^I am in \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_am_in(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        driver.get(arg1);
    }
    @Then("^It should click (\\d+) checkbox$")
    public void it_should_click_checkbox(int arg1) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id(Integer.toString(arg1))).click();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The steps will be added in the definitions class and you will be referring the `ID` there. Since you are specifying four values as `ID`, you `@tag2` scenario will run for four times and while running each time the values of `ID`will be taken accordingly. ie, while running for first time the value in `ID` will be 1, in second the `ID` value will be 2 and so on.